# How to join multiple tables group by in Entity Framework core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How to join multiple tables using group by. I have consulted some posts on stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I have Model

```
public class Customer
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string RadomID { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class RatingStore
{
  public string RadomID { get; set; }   
  public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
  public int IDProduct { get; set; }
  public string RadomID { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I count in `CustomersController`

```
public CustomersController(ApplicationDBContext context)
{
   _context = context;
}

var qr = (from Customer c in _context.Customers
                  join o in _context.RatingStore on c.RadomID equals o.RadomID
                  join p in _context.Products on c.RadomID equals p.RadomID
                  where c.Active == true
                  group c by c.RadomID into g
                  select new
                  {
                      StoreId = g.Key,
                      CountRatingStore = g.Count(),
                      CountProdStore = g.Count(),

                  }).ToList();
```

However when I debug the results

```
CountRatingStore = g.Count() --> result: 2
CountProdStore = g.Count() --> result: 2
```

It has to be like this:

```
CountRatingStore = g.Count() --> result: 1
CountProdStore = g.Count() --> result: 2
```

Because of the data in my database:

- Table Product:

[image]

- Table RatingStore:

[image]

- Table Customer:

[image]

Maybe my command is incorrect. How to get the correct result as I described above. Thank you

**Update**

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RatingStore> RatingStore { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to count the number of columns of Table Product and RatingStore with the same RandomID condition.

---> **The problem I have not been able to solve. I ask for help from everyone.**

Comment: You have to post all classes too if you need some help.

Comment: I have updated the classes I have above, thanks for the feedback

Comment: I am still trying to figure what are trying to count?

Comment: I am trying to count the number of columns of Table Product and RatingStore with the same RandomID condition.

Comment: You should create [navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key). Do not use `join`. (Something like `Customer.RatingStore.Products`). BTW, the `RatingStore` count is the same as customer count.

Comment: @GertArnold Can you clarify with your answer? I'm still confused